# Controlling a device hardware via device admin or root

Tags: java, android, admin, root

I need to have control over some admin features of android device.

Is it possible to acquire control over hardware not specified in `android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager` like disabling access to microphone?

Also it will be good to find ability to track network connections or attempts to use network adapters by apps.

Maybe some command for root console or other way exist - how I can search for?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no way to block any other hardware except camera with device manager. I believe that if your app takes control of microphone it will be unavailable to other apps, but i am not sure. Note that from android 8.0 no app is allowed to take control of microphone while in background.

About tracking network activity you could open vpn to monitor all packets that are sent and received.

Please keep in mind that i am not familiar with root methods so you should do some more research on this.